# how to perform max/mean pooling on a 2d array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, max-pooling

Given a 2D(M x N) matrix, and a 2D Kernel(K x L), how do i return a matrix that is the result of max or mean pooling using the given kernel over the image?

I'd like to use numpy if possible.

Note: M, N, K, L can be both even or odd and they need not be perfectly divisible by each other, eg: 7x5 matrix and 2x2 kernel.

eg of max pooling:

```
matrix:
array([[  20,  200,   -5,   23],
       [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
       [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
       [-120,   12,   09,   23]])
kernel: 2 x 2
soln:
array([[  200,  119],
       [  120,   49]])
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could use scikit-image [block_reduce](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce):

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage.measure

a = np.array([
      [  20,  200,   -5,   23],
      [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
      [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
      [-120,   12,    9,   23]
])
skimage.measure.block_reduce(a, (2,2), np.max)
```

Gives:

```
array([[200, 119],
       [120,  49]])
```

Comment: This is a great answer IFF you you only need to stride by your reduction size.  This API doesnt allow (yet) the ability to modify your stride (sadly). Upvoted :-)

Answer (score 40):

If the image size is evenly divisible by the kernal size, you can reshape the array and use `max` or `mean` as you see fit

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[  20,  200,   -5,   23],
       [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
       [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
       [-120,   12,   9,   23]])

M, N = mat.shape
K = 2
L = 2

MK = M // K
NL = N // L
print(mat[:MK*K, :NL*L].reshape(MK, K, NL, L).max(axis=(1, 3)))
# [[200, 119], [120, 49]]
```

If you don't have an even number of kernels, you'll have to handle the boundaries separately. (As pointed out in the comments, this results in the matrix being copied, which will affect performance).

```
mat = np.array([[20,  200,   -5,   23, 7],
                [-13,  134,  119,  100, 8],
                [120,   32,   49,   25, 12],
                [-120,   12,   9,   23, 15],
                [-57,   84,   19,   17, 82],
                ])
# soln
# [200, 119, 8]
# [120, 49, 15]
# [84, 19, 82]
M, N = mat.shape
K = 2
L = 2

MK = M // K
NL = N // L

# split the matrix into 'quadrants'
Q1 = mat[:MK * K, :NL * L].reshape(MK, K, NL, L).max(axis=(1, 3))
Q2 = mat[MK * K:, :NL * L].reshape(-1, NL, L).max(axis=2)
Q3 = mat[:MK * K, NL * L:].reshape(MK, K, -1).max(axis=1)
Q4 = mat[MK * K:, NL * L:].max()

# compose the individual quadrants into one new matrix
soln = np.vstack([np.c_[Q1, Q3], np.c_[Q2, Q4]])
print(soln)
# [[200 119   8]
#  [120  49  15]
#  [ 84  19  82]]
```

Comment: `M, N = mat.shape` would be clearer here. Also you should point out that your answer works even if the kernel doesn't divide the source, but discards the boundaries(and incurs a copy).

Comment: I have to confess, figuring out the indexing orders in `reshape` is a capability beyond programming skills. I raise my hat to @elliot .

Answer (score 22):

Instead of making "quadrants" as shown by Elliot's answer, we could pad it to make it evenly divisible, then perform either max or mean pooling.

As pooling is often used in CNN, the input array is usually 3D. So I made a function that works on either 2D or 3D arrays.

```
def pooling(mat,ksize,method='max',pad=False):
    '''Non-overlapping pooling on 2D or 3D data.

    <mat>: ndarray, input array to pool.
    <ksize>: tuple of 2, kernel size in (ky, kx).
    <method>: str, 'max for max-pooling, 
                   'mean' for mean-pooling.
    <pad>: bool, pad <mat> or not. If no pad, output has size
           n//f, n being <mat> size, f being kernel size.
           if pad, output has size ceil(n/f).

    Return <result>: pooled matrix.
    '''

    m, n = mat.shape[:2]
    ky,kx=ksize

    _ceil=lambda x,y: int(numpy.ceil(x/float(y)))

    if pad:
        ny=_ceil(m,ky)
        nx=_ceil(n,kx)
        size=(ny*ky, nx*kx)+mat.shape[2:]
        mat_pad=numpy.full(size,numpy.nan)
        mat_pad[:m,:n,...]=mat
    else:
        ny=m//ky
        nx=n//kx
        mat_pad=mat[:ny*ky, :nx*kx, ...]

    new_shape=(ny,ky,nx,kx)+mat.shape[2:]

    if method=='max':
        result=numpy.nanmax(mat_pad.reshape(new_shape),axis=(1,3))
    else:
        result=numpy.nanmean(mat_pad.reshape(new_shape),axis=(1,3))

    return result
```

Sometimes you may want to perform overlapping pooling, at a stride not equal to the kernel size. Here is a function that does that, with or without padding:

```
def asStride(arr,sub_shape,stride):
    '''Get a strided sub-matrices view of an ndarray.
    See also skimage.util.shape.view_as_windows()
    '''
    s0,s1=arr.strides[:2]
    m1,n1=arr.shape[:2]
    m2,n2=sub_shape
    view_shape=(1+(m1-m2)//stride[0],1+(n1-n2)//stride[1],m2,n2)+arr.shape[2:]
    strides=(stride[0]*s0,stride[1]*s1,s0,s1)+arr.strides[2:]
    subs=numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr,view_shape,strides=strides)
    return subs

def poolingOverlap(mat,ksize,stride=None,method='max',pad=False):
    '''Overlapping pooling on 2D or 3D data.

    <mat>: ndarray, input array to pool.
    <ksize>: tuple of 2, kernel size in (ky, kx).
    <stride>: tuple of 2 or None, stride of pooling window.
              If None, same as <ksize> (non-overlapping pooling).
    <method>: str, 'max for max-pooling,
                   'mean' for mean-pooling.
    <pad>: bool, pad <mat> or not. If no pad, output has size
           (n-f)//s+1, n being <mat> size, f being kernel size, s stride.
           if pad, output has size ceil(n/s).

    Return <result>: pooled matrix.
    '''

    m, n = mat.shape[:2]
    ky,kx=ksize
    if stride is None:
        stride=(ky,kx)
    sy,sx=stride

    _ceil=lambda x,y: int(numpy.ceil(x/float(y)))

    if pad:
        ny=_ceil(m,sy)
        nx=_ceil(n,sx)
        size=((ny-1)*sy+ky, (nx-1)*sx+kx) + mat.shape[2:]
        mat_pad=numpy.full(size,numpy.nan)
        mat_pad[:m,:n,...]=mat
    else:
        mat_pad=mat[:(m-ky)//sy*sy+ky, :(n-kx)//sx*sx+kx, ...]

    view=asStride(mat_pad,ksize,stride)

    if method=='max':
        result=numpy.nanmax(view,axis=(2,3))
    else:
        result=numpy.nanmean(view,axis=(2,3))

    return result
```

Comment: This works 30x faster compared to the scikit's block_reduce.


`block_reduce`: `9093 function calls in 0.035 seconds`


`pooling`: `10 function calls in 0.001 seconds`

Comment: @Tyathalae I may be missing some context around the analysis in your comment, but it seems to me that if there were 9093 function calls to Scikit's `block_reduce` in 0.035 seconds (1 every ~3.85μs) and only 10 function calls to the above pooling function in 0.001 seconds (1 every ~0.1ms), wouldn't that mean that Scikit's `block_reduce` is actually about ~26 times faster than the above implementation? Also, if I'm reading this correctly the difference in sample size (i.e. function calls) is very large. Could you clarify a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Greenstick, you are right, my comment is a bit ambiguous. It shows the number of functions (sub-calls) are made to complete that operation. So, scikit calls a total of `9093` sub-functions for a single `block_reduce()` call. Side note: That output format comes from `cProfile`.

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thanks for the clarification : )

Comment: Heads up: I believe `poolingOverlap` applies its kernel with the target pixel in the upper left of the kernel. This differs to the usual approach (in deep learning, in any case) of putting the target pixel in the middle of a kernel. This causes the results to be offset from what I expected.

Comment: Is there a way to also return indices of those max, to be used during backpropagation?

Comment: @Sam-gege Yes, check out this blog: https://numbersmithy.com/2d-and-3d-pooling-using-numpy/#Numpy_implementation_of_max-unpooling

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the same using `as_strided()` function of numpy. So, the idea is to create a sub-matrices of the input using the given kernel size and stride and then simply take the maximum along the height and width axes.

> **Note:** The main benefit of using this method is that it can be extended for input with channels (depth) and batches as well!

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)

# input
X = np.array([[  20,  200,   -5,   23],
              [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
              [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
              [-120,   12,    9,   23]])

Nh, Nw = X.shape # input size

Kh, Kw = (2,2) # Kernel size (along height and width)

sh, sw = (2,2) # strides along height and width

X
```

```
>>> array([[  20,  200,   -5,   23],
           [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
           [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
           [-120,   12,    9,   23]])
```

```
Oh = (Nh-Kh)//sh + 1 # output height
Ow = (Nw-Kw)//sw + 1 # output width

# creating appropriate strides
strides = (sh*Nw, sw, Nw, 1) 
strides = tuple(i * X.itemsize for i in strides) 

subM = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X, shape=(Oh, Ow, Kh, Kw),
                                       strides=strides)
subM
```

```
>>>> array([[[[  20,  200],
             [ -13,  134]],

            [[  -5,   23],
             [ 119,  100]]],


           [[[ 120,   32],
             [-120,   12]],

            [[  49,   25],
             [   9,   23]]]])
```

```
# taking maximum along the height and width axes. 
np.max(subM, axis=(2,3))
```

```
>>> array([[200, 119],
           [120,  49]])
```

We have our required output!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution uses the little-known magic of `np.maximum.at` (or you can adapt this to mean-pooling using np.add.at and dividing)

```
def max_pool(img, factor: int):
    """ Perform max pooling with a (factor x factor) kernel"""
    ds_img = np.full((img.shape[0] // factor, img.shape[1] // factor), -float('inf'), dtype=img.dtype)
    np.maximum.at(ds_img, (np.arange(img.shape[0])[:, None] // factor, np.arange(img.shape[1]) // factor), img)
    return ds_img
```

example usage:

```
img = np.array([[20, 200, -5, 23],
                [-13, 134, 119, 100],
                [120, 32, 49, 25],
                [-120, 12, 9, 23]])

print(f'Input: \n{img}')

print(f"Output: \n{max_pool(img, factor=2)}")
```

prints

```
Input: 
[[  20  200   -5   23]
 [ -13  134  119  100]
 [ 120   32   49   25]
 [-120   12    9   23]]
Output: 
[[200 119]
 [120  49]]
```

Unfortunately it appears to be a little slow though so I'd still go with the solution provided by mdh

Answer (score 1):

Since the numpy documentation says to use "numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided" with "extreme care", here is another solution for a 2D/3D pooling without it.

If strides=1, it results in using same padding. For strides>1, I am not 100% sure about how same padding is defined...

```
def pool3D(arr,
           kernel=(2, 2, 2),
           stride=(1, 1, 1),
           func=np.nanmax,
           ):
    # check inputs
    assert arr.ndim == 3
    assert len(kernel) == 3

    # create array with lots of padding around it, from which we grab stuff (could be more efficient, yes)
    arr_padded_shape = arr.shape + 2 * np.array(kernel)
    arr_padded = np.zeros(arr_padded_shape, dtype=arr.dtype) * np.nan
    arr_padded[
    kernel[0]:kernel[0] + arr.shape[0],
    kernel[1]:kernel[1] + arr.shape[1],
    kernel[2]:kernel[2] + arr.shape[2],
    ] = arr

    # create temporary array, which aggregates kernel elements in last axis
    size_x = 1 + (arr.shape[0]-1) // stride[0]
    size_y = 1 + (arr.shape[1]-1) // stride[1]
    size_z = 1 + (arr.shape[2]-1) // stride[2]
    size_kernel = np.prod(kernel)
    arr_tmp = np.empty((size_x, size_y, size_z, size_kernel), dtype=arr.dtype)

    # fill temporary array
    kx_center = (kernel[0] - 1) // 2
    ky_center = (kernel[1] - 1) // 2
    kz_center = (kernel[2] - 1) // 2
    idx_kernel = 0
    for kx in range(kernel[0]):
        dx = kernel[0] + kx - kx_center
        for ky in range(kernel[1]):
            dy = kernel[1] + ky - ky_center
            for kz in range(kernel[2]):
                dz = kernel[2] + kz - kz_center
                arr_tmp[:, :, :, idx_kernel] = arr_padded[
                                               dx:dx + arr.shape[0]:stride[0],
                                               dy:dy + arr.shape[1]:stride[1],
                                               dz:dz + arr.shape[2]:stride[2],
                                               ]
                idx_kernel += 1

    # perform pool function
    arr_final = func(arr_tmp, axis=-1)
    return arr_final


def pool2D(arr,
           kernel=(2, 2),
           stride=(1, 1),
           func=np.nanmax,
           ):
    # check inputs
    assert arr.ndim == 2
    assert len(kernel) == 2

    # transform into 3D array with empty dimension?
    arr3D = arr[..., np.newaxis]
    kernel3D = kernel + (1,)
    stride3D = stride + (1,)
    arr3D_final = pool3D(arr3D, kernel3D, stride3D, func)
    arr2D_final = arr3D_final[:, :, 0]

    return arr2D_final
```

Answer (score 0):

maxpooling for `3 x 3`  kernel and for square matrix `a`

```
a = np.array(a)
return [[a[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2].max() for j in range(1,len(a)-1)] for i in range(1,len(a)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can apply max pooling on any size kernel, using only numpy functions.

```
def max_pooling(feature_map : np.ndarray, kernel : tuple) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Applies max pooling to a feature map.

    Parameters
    ----------
    feature_map : np.ndarray
        A 2D or 3D feature map to apply max pooling to.
    kernel : tuple
        The size of the kernel to use for max pooling.

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray
        The feature map after max pooling was applied.
    """

    # Check if it fits without padding the feature map
    if feature_map.shape[0] % kernel[0] != 0:
        # Add padding to the feature map
        feature_map = np.pad(feature_map, ((0, kernel[0] - feature_map.shape[0] % kernel[0]), (0, 0), (0,0)), 'constant')
    
    if feature_map.shape[1] % kernel[1] != 0:
        feature_map = np.pad(feature_map, ((0, 0), (0, kernel[1] - feature_map.shape[1] % kernel[1]), (0,0)), 'constant')
    
    # Apply max pooling to the padded feature map
    pooled = feature_map.reshape(feature_map.shape[0] // kernel[0], 
                                 kernel[0], 
                                 feature_map.shape[1] // kernel[1], 
                                 kernel[1]
                                 ).max(axis=(1, 3))
    return pooled
```

Answer (score 0):

### Only using Numpy, python loop

---

<kbd>Python</kbd> <kbd>Numpy</kbd> <kbd>MaxPooling</kbd>

This is generic solution, so you can adjust stride, pooling and kernel

*for this example : **strids=2**, **kernel=2**, **pooling=0***

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

#create a dummy input array
data = np.array([[  20,  200,   -5,   23],
              [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
              [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
              [-120,   12,    9,   23]])


shape = data.shape
pading = 0
kernel = 2
stride = 2

height = shape[0] + (pading * 2)
width = shape[1] + (pading * 2)
data = data.astype(np.int32)
data = np.pad(data, (pading,pading))

eq = ((height - kernel) // stride) + 1  # input_dim - filter_dim / stride + 1

pooled = []
for h in range(0, height, stride):
    for w in range(0, width, stride):
        if h > height - kernel or w > width - kernel:
            continue
        slice_array = data[h:h + kernel, w:w + kernel]
        val = int(np.max(slice_array)) #max
        #val = int(np.mean(slice_array)) #mean
        pooled.append(val)

pooled = np.array(pooled, np.int32).reshape(eq,eq)
print(pooled)
# array([[  200,  119],
#       [  120,   49]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view) looks more intuitive (not sure about the performance):

```py
assert data.shape == (h, w, ...) # The first two dimensions are the height and width
windows = sliding_window_view(data, (k, k), axis=(0, 1))[::stride, ::stride]
max_pooled = windows.max(axis=(-2, -1))
```

where `k` corresponds to the kernel size.