# Implement max/mean pooling(with stride) with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, conv-neural-network

I wanted to know how to implement a simple max/mean pooling with numpy. I was reading [Max and mean pooling with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463172/how-to-perform-max-mean-pooling-on-a-2d-array-using-numpy), but unfortunately it assumed the stride was the same as the kernel size. Is there a numpythonic way to do this? Also it would be nice if this were to work for any dimension, but of course not neccesary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a pure numpy implementation using [stride_tricks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


def pool2d(A, kernel_size, stride, padding=0, pool_mode='max'):
   '''
    2D Pooling

    Parameters:
        A: input 2D array
        kernel_size: int, the size of the window over which we take pool
        stride: int, the stride of the window
        padding: int, implicit zero paddings on both sides of the input
        pool_mode: string, 'max' or 'avg'
    '''
    # Padding
    A = np.pad(A, padding, mode='constant')

    # Window view of A
    output_shape = ((A.shape[0] - kernel_size) // stride + 1,
                    (A.shape[1] - kernel_size) // stride + 1)
    
    shape_w = (output_shape[0], output_shape[1], kernel_size, kernel_size)
    strides_w = (stride*A.strides[0], stride*A.strides[1], A.strides[0], A.strides[1])
    
    A_w = as_strided(A, shape_w, strides_w)

    # Return the result of pooling
    if pool_mode == 'max':
        return A_w.max(axis=(2, 3))
    elif pool_mode == 'avg':
        return A_w.mean(axis=(2, 3))
```

Example:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 4],
                  [5, 6, 7, 8],
                  [3, 2, 1, 0],
                  [1, 2, 3, 4]])

>>> pool2d(A, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, pool_mode='max')

array([[6, 8],
       [3, 4]])
```

[image]

https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Comment: Nice, you can also make this work for stacks of 2d arrays (usually the output of convolutional layer) with `np.array([pool2d(channel, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, pool_mode='max') for channel in A])`. Of course, considering `A` is 3d array.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide an alternative answer to the stride based approached offered by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54966908/23243515). This is because the documentation for the [as_strided()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) function explicitly states the following:

> ...arrays created with this function often contain self overlapping memory, so that two elements are identical. Vectorized write operations on such arrays will typically be unpredictable. They may even give different results for small, large, or transposed arrays.... For these reasons it is advisable to avoid as_strided when possible.

I am generally not comfortable with the level of unpredictability that as_strided() contains. Particularly since write operations are quite common for the image after it has been strided.

The following algorithm uses default numpy functions to generate a max pooling effect. It is limited to a kernel size of (2,2) and a stride of (1,1), however you can emulate larger kernels by running the max pooling function multiple times.

```
import numpy as np

def LocalMaximums(img_orig):
    img = np.pad(img_orig, (1,), "edge")
    img_list = [
        img,
        np.roll(img, 1, axis = 0),
        np.roll(img, -1, axis = 0),
        np.roll(img, 1, axis = 1),
        np.roll(img, -1, axis = 1),
        np.roll(img, (1, 1), axis = (0, 1)),
        np.roll(img, (-1, 1), axis = (0, 1)),
        np.roll(img, (1, -1), axis = (0, 1)),
        np.roll(img, (-1, -1), axis = (0, 1))
    ]

    img_merged = np.stack(img_list)
    img_maxed = np.max(img_merged, axis = 0)
    img_maxed = img_maxed[1:-1, 1:-1]

    return img_maxed

shape0 = [4, 4]
shape1 = [8, 8]

# Create test images
img0 = np.arange(0, shape0[0] * shape0[1]).reshape(shape0[0], shape0[1])
img1 = np.arange(0, shape1[0] * shape1[1]).reshape(shape1[0], shape1[1])

# Re-arrange rows to demonstrate more interesting behavior
img0 = img0[[1, 0, 2, 3], :]
img1 = img1[[1, 0, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6], :]

print("=================================")
print("   Original Images")
print("=================================")
print(img0, "\n")
print(img1, "\n")

img0_max = LocalMaximums(img0)
img1_max = LocalMaximums(img1)

print("=================================")
print("   Maxed Images: 1 Iteration")
print("   Equivalent to max pooling with kernel=(3,3) and stride=(1,1)")
print("=================================")
print(img0_max, "\n")
print(img1_max, "\n")

img0_max = LocalMaximums(img0_max)
img1_max = LocalMaximums(img1_max)

print("=================================")
print("   Maxed Images: 2 Iterations")
print("   Equivalent to max pooling with kernel=(5,5) and stride=(1,1)")
print("=================================")
print(img0_max, "\n")
print(img1_max, "\n")
```

Output:

```
=================================
   Original Images
=================================
[[ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]

[[ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
 [56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63]
 [32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]
 [48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55]]

=================================
   Maxed Images: 1 Iteration
   Equivalent to max pooling with kernel=(3,3) and stride=(1,1)
=================================
[[ 5  6  7  7]
 [ 9 10 11 11]
 [13 14 15 15]
 [13 14 15 15]]

[[ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15]
 [17 18 19 20 21 22 23 23]
 [25 26 27 28 29 30 31 31]
 [57 58 59 60 61 62 63 63]
 [57 58 59 60 61 62 63 63]
 [57 58 59 60 61 62 63 63]
 [49 50 51 52 53 54 55 55]
 [49 50 51 52 53 54 55 55]]

=================================
   Maxed Images: 2 Iterations
   Equivalent to max pooling with kernel=(5,5) and stride=(1,1)
=================================
[[10 11 11 11]
 [14 15 15 15]
 [14 15 15 15]
 [14 15 15 15]]

[[18 19 20 21 22 23 23 23]
 [26 27 28 29 30 31 31 31]
 [58 59 60 61 62 63 63 63]
 [58 59 60 61 62 63 63 63]
 [58 59 60 61 62 63 63 63]
 [58 59 60 61 62 63 63 63]
 [58 59 60 61 62 63 63 63]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 55 55]]
```

The growth of the img_list is O(2n), where n is the number of dimensions in the kernel. If you're inclined, extending the code to support arbitrary strides, kernel sizes, and additional dimensions should not be too difficult.

At the very least, this approach works well enough for the single channel 2D matrices we often see during a typical image processing pipeline. Besides, if you're trying to work with anything more complicated than that, you're likely better off using a heavy-duty library like [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) that has explicitly defined modules for such behaviors.