# Reordering block matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multi-index

I have a multi-level indexed square matrix, that needs to be reordered.
Say I have a two-level indexing system `x` and `y` and the square matrix `M` has the shape `(len(x)*len(y), len(x)*len(y))`.
`M` is sorted by the `x` index and I want to transform it to be sorted by the `y` index. Here is an example to contruct an arbitary square matrix `M`:

```
import numpy as np
nx = 4  # equal to len(x), arbitary
ny = 3  # equal to len(y), arbitary
A=np.ones(ny*ny).reshape(ny,ny) #arbitary
B=np.ones(ny*ny).reshape(ny,ny)*2 #arbitary
C=np.ones(ny*ny).reshape(ny,ny)*3 #arbitary
D=np.ones(ny*ny).reshape(ny,ny)*4 #arbitary
E=np.arange(ny*ny).reshape(ny,ny) #arbitary
M = np.block([[A, np.zeros((ny,ny)), E, np.zeros((ny,ny))],
              [np.zeros((ny,ny)), B, np.zeros((ny,ny)),np.zeros((ny,ny))], 
              [np.zeros((ny,ny)),np.zeros((ny,ny)),C, np.zeros((ny,ny))],
              [np.zeros((ny,ny)), np.zeros((ny,ny)), np.zeros((ny,ny)), D]])
```

and the resulting matrix M may look like this

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 3., 4., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 6., 7., 8., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 4., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 4., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 4., 4.]])
```

Now I want to transform the `M` into `M_transformed` that looks like this

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4.],
       [1., 0., 3., 0., 1., 0., 4., 0., 1., 0., 5., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4.],
       [1., 0., 6., 0., 1., 0., 7., 0., 1., 0., 8., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4.]])
```

I use a very elementary, 4 layers of for loops to solve this problem and I believe there must be a more straight forward way (like a library) to solve this issue, as the matrix `M` can grow very large depending on the length of `x` and `y` (`nx` and `ny`)

```
M_transformed = np.zeros(M.shape)

for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(nx):
        for k in range(ny):
            for l in range(ny):
                M_transformed[k * nx + i,l * nx + j] = M[i * ny + k, j * ny + l]
```

Comment: I haven't tried to follow all of your logic, but sticking with a 2d array like this may be making things harder than they need to be.  If the array was 4d, which could be thought of as a 2d array of 2d blocks, reordering the subblocks is easier. And for some reorderings, a transpose (or axis swap) might be in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with no calculations, just borrowing some ideas from [how to do maxpooling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463514) and experimenting a lot with swaps of axes.

I came to solution with this plan:

[image]

And this is my solution:

```
w = (3, 3)
initial_shape = M.shape
M = M.reshape((M.shape[0]//w[0], w[0], M.shape[1]//w[1], w[1]))
M = M.swapaxes(0, 1)
M = M.swapaxes(2, 3)
M = M.reshape(initial_shape)
```